# Definir tipo de variable en una funcion

Tags: python

Buenas, estoy aprendiendo Python y tenia curiosidad, ya que soy nuevo en esto de la programación, al declarar una variable en una función, ¿no se puede especificar el tipo de variable como si lo hicieras normalmente? Yo quiero hacer esto pero se ve que no me deja el programa.

```
def es_par(int(numero)):
if numero%2==0:
    return True
else:
    return False
print(es_par(input("Introduce un numero")))
```

La única solución que encuentro es hacer esto:

```
def es_par(numero):
if numero%2==0:
    return True
else:
    return False
print(es_par(int(input("Introduce un numero"))))
```

Muchas gracias y perdón por mi ignorancia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python los tipos de datos se calculan sobre la marcha (dinámico). 
Lo que puedes hacer es comprobar si es un entero y si no, generar una excepción de tipo incorrecto.

```
    def esPar(n):
       if not isinstance(n, (int, long)):
           raise TypeError('no es un entero')
       return n % 2 == 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, responde bien a mi pregunta :)

Comment: @DavidHidalgoMuñoz Si te ha servido marca la respuesta como válida para que los usuarios que tengan la misma duda puedan encontrar-la fácilmente.

Answer (score 4):

Es posible indicar el tipo con *anotaciones de tipo* (*"tipado gradual"*):

```
def es_par(numero: int) -> bool:
    return numero%2 == 0
```

Pero es sólo una indicación, no previene errores si pasas argumentos de otro tipo. En python no hay *"tipado estático"*.